# need shellscript to read the value in file1.xml and copy the value and search the value in another file2 and paste the value under it

Tags: shell

I had a scenario, where I need to read a properties file (.xml) and update the value in profile file (eg: txt or .xml)

also there will be multiple profile files created with adding numbers for increment, need to read properties file value based on the name of the profile file and copy the value.

properties file (.xml):

```html
<Properties>
<Node>
<AppnodeName>Node1</AppnodeName>
<Property>
<Name>//I-080_Control_CostCenter_test//FT.DEPLOYMENT.NAME</Name>
<Value>Value1</Value>
</Property>
<Property>
<Name>//I-080_Control_CostCenter_test//FT.DEPLOYMENT.VERSION</Name>
<Value>Value11</Value>
</Property>
</Node>
<Node>
<AppnodeName>Node2</AppnodeName>
<Property>
<Name>//I-080_Control_CostCenter_test//FT.DEPLOYMENT.NAME</Name>
<Value>Value2</Value>
</Property>
<Property>
<Name>//I-080_Control_CostCenter_test//FT.DEPLOYMENT.VERSION</Name>
<Value>Value12</Value>
</Property>
</Node>
</Properties>
```

====================================================

Profile file:

will be similar, need to search for the appnodename, name and update the Value.

Please help me

Comment: What did you try? Is the XML file always formatted **exactly** like you posted it, or can there be some variations is spacing (white space, newlines)?

Comment: yes, the xml file given by team is same as mentioned above.

Comment: There are two values. (Value1 and Value11). Which one do you want to change?

Comment: @user1934428 both values need to be changed.

Comment: You have only one Appnodename in the file. So you don't need to find a certain appnodename. You just have to change all `<Value>` lines in the file.

Comment: let say, there are multiple nodes node1, node2, need to search for name and update the value under it.

Comment: Read the file line-by-line (XML parsing is not necessary, since you said that the file is always formatted in this way) from stdin. If you encounter a nodename you are interested in, set a flag that you are now interested in the value. If you encounter a value line and the flag is set, write the updated value line to stdout. If you encounter a nodename you are not interested in, reset the flag.

Comment: @user1934428 Sorry, iam new to scripting, still unable to understand, can you give an example script if possible.

Comment: In stackoverflow, one question is to suppose to focus on a single problem. I already provided a layout for a possible algorithm. If you are stuck at a certain point, please ask a question about this specific problem. However, I don't think that you can not understand how to read a file line by line; if you google for this, you will find many examples.